# CALL TWO MYSQL STORED PROCEDURES FROM PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm getting this error when I try to call 2 stored procedures from my php code....

How can I do this 2 calls? Which method can I use?? Thank you!!

ERROR:

```
Error Number: 2014

Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

When I call the functions...

```
$aFrecClientes = $this->summary_model->get_frecClientes($this->session->userdata('USER_ID'));

$aResumenAnual = $this->summary_model->get_resumenAnual($anyo,$this->session->userdata('USER_ID'));
```

My calls' functions:

```
public function get_frecClientes($id_empresa){
        $oQuery = $this->db->query("CALL GET_FRECUENCIACLIENTES(1);");


        $aResult = $oQuery->result_array();
        return $aResult;
     } 


     public function get_resumenAnual(){
        $oQuery = $this->db->query("CALL GET_RESUMENANUAL (1, 102);");



        $aResult = $oQuery->result_array();

        return $aResult;
     }
```

AND MY STORED PROCEDURES:

```
BEGIN
SELECT uu.MES, SUM(uu.INGRESOS) INGRESOS, SUM(uu.GASTOS) GASTOS, SUM(uu.INGRESOS)-SUM(uu.GASTOS) RESULTAT
FROM ( 
       -- INGRESOS
       SELECT MONTH(FECHA) MES, 
               SUM(F.TOTALFACTURA) INGRESOS,
               0 GASTOS
       FROM FACTURASCLIENTES F
       LEFT JOIN CLIENTES C ON C.IDCLIENTE = F.IDCLIENTE
       WHERE C.IDEMPRESA = IDEMPRESA 
       AND F.FECHABORRADO IS NULL AND YEAR(FECHA)=ANYO
       GROUP BY MONTH(FECHA)

       UNION

       SELECT MONTH(FECHA) MES, 
                SUM(IMPORTE) INGRESOS,
                0 GASTOS
       FROM TICKETS 
       INNER JOIN  TIPOSTICKETS on (TICKETS.IDTIPOTICKET = TIPOSTICKETS.IDTIPOTICKET)
       INNER JOIN TRADUCCIONES on (TIPOSTICKETS.IDTRADUCCION = TRADUCCIONES.IDTRADUCCION AND TIPOSTICKETS.IDTRADUCCIONTABLA  = TRADUCCIONES.IDTRADUCCIONTABLA ) 
       WHERE IDEMPRESA = IDEMPRESA 
       AND TRADUCCIONES.ESP = "INGRESOS" AND TICKETS.FECHABORRADO IS NULL
       AND YEAR(FECHA)=ANYO
       GROUP BY MONTH(FECHA)

       UNION

       -- GASTOS
       SELECT MONTH(FECHA) MES, 
               0 INGRESOS,
               SUM(FP.TOTALFACTURA) GASTOS
       FROM FACTURASPROVEEDORES FP
       INNER JOIN PROVEEDORES P on P.IDPROVEEDOR = FP.IDPROVEEDOR
       WHERE P.IDEMPRESA = IDEMPRESA 
       AND FP.FECHABORRADO IS NULL
       AND YEAR(FECHA)=ANYO
       GROUP BY MONTH(FECHA)


       UNION

       SELECT MONTH(FECHA) MES, 
                0 INGRESOS,
                SUM(NETO) GASTOS
       FROM TICKETS
       INNER JOIN  TIPOSTICKETS on (TICKETS.IDTIPOTICKET = TIPOSTICKETS.IDTIPOTICKET)
       INNER JOIN TRADUCCIONES on (TIPOSTICKETS.IDTRADUCCION = TRADUCCIONES.IDTRADUCCION AND TIPOSTICKETS.IDTRADUCCIONTABLA  = TRADUCCIONES.IDTRADUCCIONTABLA ) 
       WHERE IDEMPRESA = IDEMPRESA 
       AND TRADUCCIONES.ESP = "INGRESOS" AND TICKETS.FECHABORRADO IS NULL
       AND YEAR(FECHA)=ANYO
       GROUP BY MONTH(FECHA)
       ) uu   
GROUP BY uu.MES;
END
```

MY SECOND PROCEDURE:

```
BEGIN
        DECLARE NumeroFacturas bigint;
        Select NumeroFacturas = SUM(TOTALFACTURA) 
        from FACTURASCLIENTES FC
        inner join CLIENTES C on C.IDCLIENTE = FC.IDCLIENTE
        where FC.FECHABORRADO IS NULL and C.IDEMPRESA = IDEMPRESA;

        Select C.NOMBRE, ROUND((SUM(TOTALFACTURA) * 100 / NumeroFacturas),0) FRECUENCIA
        From CLIENTES C
        inner join FACTURASCLIENTES FC on C.IDCLIENTE = FC.IDCLIENTE
        where C.IDEMPRESA = IDEMPRESA and FC.FECHABORRADO IS NULL
        GROUP BY C.NOMBRE
        ORDER BY FRECUENCIA DESC
        LIMIT 6;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Refere below links:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-use-result.html

reason for above error is that you does not use result of first query and fire second query.